# Is there a way to show that two groups are isomorphic by visual representation(Cayley diagram)?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I got a question asking me to prove that $V_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$ are isomorphic.

I can do this algebraically. However, I am curious if there is there a way to explain this using the diagram?

Thanks.

Edit: If the Cayley graph looks the same, are they isomorphic? And if not, then how? Also, I am stuck on how to draw $C_2 \times C_2$ Cayley graph.

Comment: Just to be clear - by Cayley diagram you mean the group multiplication table? Or do you mean the "Cayley graph" associated to a group along with a generating set?

Comment: What is your definition of $V_4$, if *not* $C_2\times C_2$?

Comment: $V_4$ is Klein-4 and $C_2$ is cyclic group of order 2

Comment: @ZevChonoles A fairly common definition of $V_4$ (though maybe not with those words) is to take the commutator subgroup of $A_4$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles It is often defined as a certain subgroup of $S_4$ or just by giving the group operation explicitly on the set $\{1,a,b,c\}$.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I mean Cayley graph http://www.weddslist.com/groups/cayley-31/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if two groups have the same Cayley graph*, then they are isomorphic. But note that for a given group, by choosing different generating sets, you can produce non-isomorphic Cayley graphs.

For example, the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z},$ with the usual generateors $\{+1,-1\}$, is an infinite line with vertices at the integers. Notice there are no cycles. But if we look at the Cayley graph with respect to the generating set $\{2,3,-2,-3\}$, then you will get cycles; hence the graphs are note isomorphic. Nevertheless, if you zoom out and ignore the small scale structure, it looks a lot like the first graph. If this example is interesting, you can check out Wikipedia's article on [Quasi-isometrys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry).

*Edit: Note the comment by user1729. Yes, the graph does need to be labeled. One way would be as in the definition found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph).

Comment: When you say "the same Cayley graph" do you mean "the same graph underlying the Cayley graph", or are you assuming it is labelled? If the former, do you have a reference?

Comment: Actually, the former interpretation is definitely not true. For example, compare the Cayley graph of $C_2\times C_2=\langle a, b\rangle$ with the Cayley graph of $C_4=\langle a, a^{1-}\rangle$. The graphs, including all arrows, are the same. It is the labels that matter.

Comment: Thank you; great point. The unlabeled Cayley graph of $C_4 = \langle a, a^{-1} \rangle$ is isomorphic to the unlabeled Cayley graph of $C_2 \times C_2 = \langle a, b \rangle$.

Comment: A simpler counterexample for unlabeled Cayley graphs:  Any two finite groups of the same order, with the entire group taken as a generating set.